# Cannot Find method error

Tags: java, methods, find

Below is my code for the Star constructor, i'm passing the correct values but i keep getting a cannot find symbol error for the star constructor

```
private Star[] star;
st = db.readLineFromDB();
ST = new StringTokenizer(st , ",");
star[count] = Star.Star(Double.valueOf(ST.nextToken()),Double.valueOf(ST.nextToken()),ST.nextToken(),Integer.valueOf(ST.nextToken()),ST.nextToken());
count++;

public Star(double logdist, double vmag, String sp_class, int ID, String name)
 {
 this.logdist = logdist;
 this.vmag = vmag;
 this.sp_class = sp_class;
 this.ID = ID;
 this.name = name;
 }
```

Thanks guys for the ans... about to give up...

Answer (score 1):

```
star[count] = new Star(...);
```

You invoke constructors with the `new` keyword, not with `Class.Class(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Star.Star(Double.valueOf(ST.nextToken()),Double.valueOf(ST.nextToken()),ST.nextToken(),Integer.valueOf(ST.nextToken()),ST.nextToken());
```

This is not the way to call constructor.

you should do some thing

```
Star starObj = new Star(Double.valueOf(ST.nextToken()),Double.valueOf(ST.nextToken()),ST.nextToken(),Integer.valueOf(ST.nextToken()),ST.nextToken());
```

[**Have a detail look at this tutorial**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
star[count] = Star.Star(Double.valueOf(ST.nextToken()),Double.valueOf(ST.nextToken()),ST.nextToken(),Integer.valueOf(ST.nextToken()),ST.nextToken());
```

do

```
star[count] = new Star(Double.valueOf(ST.nextToken()),Double.valueOf(ST.nextToken()),ST.nextToken(),Integer.valueOf(ST.nextToken()),ST.nextToken());
```

The `Star` method isn't a public static class so you can't do `Star.Star` (if that's possible).